# i can't access a file path vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i really don't understand , the code is clear and simple , my app throw exception when i want to read the path of an existing file .

the error : "the given path's format is not supported"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXNTN.png

even if i changed the path it's the same problem

that's my code :

```
    Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
    testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("‪C:\Users\ochallal\Desktop\ENQ1620_3.sdf")
    Dim folderPath As String = testFile.DirectoryName
    Dim fileName As String = testFile.Name
    Dim fullPath As String
    fullPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(folderPath, fileName)
```

and that's the details of the exception

https://i.stack.imgur.com/njJcv.png

i'm guessing that it could be permission stuff but i have all permissions and using visual studio as Administartor

Comment: What kind of drive is `D:\ `? CD/DVD, USB, HDD, Network, other?

Comment: HDD ,  it's the same error when i move the file to C:\

Comment: What happens if you try doing it the .NET way instead: `testFile = New System.IO.FileInfo("D:\ENQ1620_3.sdf")`?

Comment: Do you have an OS in that disk (in `C:` pretty sure)? Have you tested it with a sub-folder?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Please post as text as part of your question formatted as code. We cannot copy your code to test it from an image.

Comment: Visual Vicent : yes i did , i got the same error . Jimi: yes i do , i tested on any directory and it's the same problem . Mary : i did add the code . Thanks guys for replying . any other suggestions ?

Comment: This is an ancient way to address a path. Also, your Path contains an invalid char, right after the first quote. Try changing it in: `Dim MyPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ENQ1620_3.sdf")`  Dim testFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(MyPath)` and see what you get. Then, closely inspect the string you provided, moving the caret along its length. You'll see that is stops for no apparent reason at (char) position 1. Don't use paths like that. Update your coding style to the .Net methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy your text and paste it in Visual Studio, and look with a hex editor at it I see some extra bytes in the string:

[image]

Remove that and it will work.

Comment: And this is why it is important to copy and paste the code into the question rather than as an image!